# Cast from array causing crash on some MCUs but not others

Tags: c, stm32

I have a piece of code looking like this:

```
void update_clock(uint8_t *time_array)
{
    time_t time = *((time_t *) &time_array[0]); // <-- hangs
    /* ... more code ... */
}
```

Where `time_array` is an array of 4 bytes (i.e. `uint8_t time_array[4]`).

I'm using arm-none-eabi-gcc to compile this for an STM32L4 processor.

While compiling this a couple of months ago I got no errors and the code is running perfectly fine on all my test MCUs. I did some updates to my environment (OpenSTM32) when coming back to this project and now this piece of code is crashing on some MCUs while working fine on others.

I still have my binary from a couple of months ago and have confirmed that this code path works fine on all of my MCUs (I have about 5 to test on), but now it works on two of them while causing a crash on three of them.

I have mitigated the problem by rewriting the code like this:

```
time_t time = (
        ((uint32_t) time_array[0]) << 0 |
        ((uint32_t) time_array[1]) << 8 |
        ((uint32_t) time_array[2]) << 16 |
        ((uint32_t) time_array[3]) << 24
);
```

While this works for now, I think the old code looks cleaner and I'm also worried that if this code path hangs I probably will have similar errors elsewhere.

Does anyone have any idea what can be causing this? Can I change anything in my setup to make the compiler work the old way again?

Comment: `(time_t *) &time_array[0]` breaks strict aliasing. And isn't endianness aware. And dereferencing that pointer will cause problems on targets where words must be aligned, and your array isn't properly aligned.

Comment: Are you sure the size of time_t has remained constant and that time_array always points to at least that many bytes?

Comment: What do you mean by "some MCUs"? Different models? Is this bare-metal code or are you running with an OS?

Comment: @Vroomfondel bare metal code. The test boards all have the same MCU model.

Comment: And some crash always (deterministically, after the same time) and some never? Did you runn all of them long enough?

Comment: @Vroomfondel 3 of the MCUs always hangs until the watchdog collects them (almost 80ms if memory recalls, more than enough time for this code to finish). 2 of them never have any trouble.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the info. I guess I'll have to comb through the code to check for other instances where this practice is used or is there any flag to turn this into a warning?

Comment: What compiler are you using in OpenSTM32?

Comment: `time_t` may have alignments requirements more strict than `uin8_t` --> `(time_t *) &time_array[0]` --> UB.  "Can I change anything in my setup" --> Question here lacks the setup.  Post an [mcve]

Comment: So the boards are identical (i.e. same CPUs, same amount of RAM, etc.), correct? Is it always the same boards that fails? Or will a specific board fail somethimes and work other times?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it does not not matter in this case. It is STM32 CortexM code, endianes are always the same and the aliasing rules do not change anything. This code is not going to ported to the other platform as it is a specific hardware dependent.

Comment: @gurglet what does it mean hangs (crashes)? HF? Or something else

Comment: @chux - Cortex-M4 doeas not need the aligned access. Only the peripherals like DMA for example may have such a requirements

Comment: @P__J__ That depends, `LDRD`, `STRD`, `LDM`, and `STM` do require word alignment and will cause a usagefault if not. See the http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/Bhcjabhi.html description of UNALIGN_TRP there.

Comment: @Colin which is 100% unrelated to this case. BTW Compiler will never generate LDRD instruction for the possible unaligned data.

Comment: @P__J__ That's exactly what it is in this case, see https://godbolt.org/g/aEd31o

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/zQC2ej see the difference?

Comment: @P__J__ In your example the compiler knows that &array[1] is unaligned so generates the correct instructions, in the OP's code it doesn't, it's just dereferencing a `time_t *` which it assumes is aligned. Compile your code again with `-Os` so the compiler doesn't inline the `UpdateClock` function and you have the same problem. See https://godbolt.org/g/Mj6iEb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From version 7-2017-q4-major, arm gcc ships with newlib compiled with `time_t` defined as 64 bit (`long long`) integer, causing all sorts of problems with code that assumes it to be 32 bits. Your code is reading past the end of the source array, taking whatever is stored there as the *high order bits* of the time value, possibly resulting in a date before the big bang, or after the heat death of the universe, which might not be what your code expects.

If the source array is known to contain 32 bits of data, copy it to a 32 bit `int32_t` variable first, then you can assign it to a `time_t`, this way it will be properly converted, regardless of the size of `time_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Your development environment OpenSTM32 may be using a gcc compiler. If so, gcc supports the following macro flag.

```
-fno-strict-aliasing
```

It you are using `-O2`, this flag might resolve your problem.

Using `memcpy` is the standard advice, and is sometimes optimized-away by the compiler:

```
memcpy(&time, time_array, sizeof time);
```

Finally, you can use `gcc`'s `typeof` and a compound literal with a union to generate the following safe cast:

```
#define PUN_CAST4(a, x)  ((union {uint8_t src[4]; typeof(x) dst;}){{a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]}}).dst
time_t time = PUN_CAST4(time_array, time);
```

As an example, the following code is compiled at https://godbolt.org/g/eZRXxW:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

time_t update_clock(uint8_t *time_array) {
    time_t t = *((time_t *) &time_array[0]);  // assumes no alignment problem
    return t;
}

time_t update_clock2(uint8_t *time_array) {
    time_t t =
        (uint32_t)time_array[0] << 0 |
        (uint32_t)time_array[1] << 8 |
        (uint32_t)time_array[2] << 16 |
        (uint32_t)time_array[3] << 24;
    return t;
}

time_t update_clock3(uint8_t *time_array) {
    time_t t;
    memcpy(&t, time_array, sizeof t);
    return t;
}

#define PUN_CAST4(a, x)  ((union {uint8_t src[4]; typeof(x) dst;}){{a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]}}).dst

time_t update_clock4(uint8_t *time_array) {
    time_t t = PUN_CAST4(time_array, t);
    return t;
}
```

gcc 8.1 is good for all four examples: it generates the trivial code with `-O2`. But gcc 7.3 is bad for the 4th. Clang is also good for all four with `-m32` for a 32-bit target, but fails on the 2nd and 4th without it

Comment: **Edit:** Interestingly, with armv7, the `memcpy` code is poor, while the other three seem ok; see https://godbolt.org/g/g7wJPN.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is caused by unaligned access, or writing to the wrong area.

Compiling

```
#include "stdint.h"
#include "time.h"

time_t myTime;
void update_clock(uint8_t *time_array)
{
    myTime = *((time_t *) &time_array[0]); // <-- hangs
    /* ... more code ... */
}
```

with GCC 7.2.1 with the arguments `-march=armv7-m -Os` generates the following

```
update_clock(unsigned char*):
        ldr     r3, .L2
        ldrd    r0, [r0]
        strd    r0, [r3]
        bx      lr
.L2:
        .word   .LANCHOR0
myTime:
```

Because your time array is an 8 bit type there are no rules for alignment, so if the linker has not word aligned it, when you try and dereference it as a `time_t *` the `LDRD` instruction is given a non word aligned address and causes a usagefault.

The `LDRD` and `STRD` instructions are loading and storing 8 bytes, whereas your array is only 4 bytes long. I suggest you check `sizeof(time_t)` in your environment, and make an aligned area long enough to store it.

Comment: and the same code on the same machine sometimes is aligned sometimes not? Be serious.

Comment: Who knows? If they're dynamically allocated there may be a race condition causing them to end up in different places. If you know something to the contrary feel free to add your own answer.

Comment: Dynamic allocation is aligned by default. 7.20.3. otherwise is not C compliant.

Comment: Sorry, a misuse of terms on my part. If the array is stack allocated.

Comment: Stack is always native size aligned as well. Only the packed structs may cause the problem https://godbolt.org/g/M9RRwA

Comment: Or more than native :https://godbolt.org/g/QZs2C6. Never byte aligned. That is the reason gcc assumes the 4 byte alignment of the pointers. keil has __packed attribute showing that the pointer might not be native aligned. gcc is missing this feature